# Connecting Oracle from Linux

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have an oracle instance running on windows on localhost port 1521. If I try to test the connection with appropriate username and password along with the jdbc string `jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/ORCL` in sqldeveloper then I get a success.
But my service is running on linux virtual machine and the service exposes an UI which takes the jdbc connection string of the oracle instance inorder to connect to the database. With the username, password and jdbc connection string it is unable to establish a connection to the oracle database.
I have `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora` files in network configurations of oracle where HOST is specified as `localhost`.
Any idea on what has to be done ?
Port forwarding ?

Thanks,

Comment: Well, what is the error?

Comment: `JDBC_00 - Cannot connect to specified database. JDBC_06- Failed to initialize connection pool : Exception during pool initialization : IO Error: Network adapter could not establish connection.`

Comment: One thing is - your Linux VM is not hosting the instance, hence you can't use localhost, but instead need an IP of the Windows machine.

Comment: @access_granted Tried that but with no success.

Comment: Try pinging the host:port from the LVM

Comment: @access_granted packets are transferred but not received when I my machine is on host only adapter mode. When on NAT, ping is received but I can't see my service's UI on browser.

Comment: not a network expert (which is what it should probably be reclassified to as a topic), but if you can telnet to the box/port from the command line, you should also be able to open a thin jdbc connection, in my experience